# submit() function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have the following code for which submit() function just don't work. I know i am missing something very simple but i am unable to figure it out.

**HTML**

```
    <form id="form" method="post" action="/url/">
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="hidden">
    </form>
    <span id="diagnose"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></span>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).diagnose();
    </script>
```

**Jquery**

```
(function( $ ){
$.fn.diagnose = function(){

    $("#diagnose").click(function(){
        //window.location.href = "/url"; //This works
    ('#form').submit(); // This doesn't
    });
};
}( jQuery ));
```

Comment: Should be `$('#form').submit();`, you forgot `$`

Comment: ohh yess!! i knew this would be something this silly.

Comment: how did i miss that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options

- remove # and add `document.getElementById('form').submit();` for pure javascript
- add $ `$('#form').submit();` for jQuery

Answer (score 2):

I think you're missing the $ in front of the ('#form') selector...

Answer (score 1):

u forgot something :

```
('#form').submit(); // This doesn't
```

try to add $.